# Populate new array in for loop from two other arrays

Tags: php, arrays, range

Hi I have been struggling with population of an array if you can help it will be much appreciated.

So I have these two arrays `$start_range[]` and `$end_range[]` which both contain 
respective values and both arrays are of the same size. For example: `$start_range[0] = 1000` and `$end_range[0]=[2000]`. Now I want to fill a new array with the range between those numbers and keep the respectiveness of the values so as in the example `$new_array[0] = range($start_range[0],$end_range[0])`.

In the moment I am using this code here

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($start_range); $i++) { 
   $new_array[] = range($start_range[$i], $end_range[$i]);
}
```

But my problem is that it generates arrays with the same data because it loops through the size of the array. As if the size of the array was 4 then it will generate 4 new exact same arrays. I can't break out of the loop as it generates arrays only from the first columns of the two arrays.

Any solution?

Comment: From my reading of your description, it sounds like it's working exactly as intended, but that is apparently not so. Can you post a small sample from the two input arrays and what the expected output array would look like? It's most difficult to understand what the structure of the output would be, if it isn't what your code already produces.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I can't as it is on my work station. I retyped the code from memory on my own pc. I will try and post it first thing tomorrow morning. I think its mostly a typo somewhere but from the other hand it generates new arrays each time it loops.

Comment: More than anything it would just help to see what the `$new_array` should look like. For example given ranges 1..3 and 20..23 your existing code produces `array(array(1,2,3), array(20,21,22,23))` but it sounds like maybe what you want is a single continuous array like `array(1,2,3,20,21,22,23)`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($startArray as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$key] = range($startArray[$key], $endArray[$key]);
}
```